# Is there a difference between 出来る and 作る。

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I was in a discussion with someone online, and wanted to know if both terms can be used similarly. Thank you.

Comment: Your change of title does not work.  作る is not read できる、 but is rather read as つくる。If you wrote 出来る as できる that would make more sense.

Comment: @ajsmart, I have posted the original content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I don't see how they can be similar.